# What is the function of il in "venite il prima possibile"？

Tags: grammar, articles

As stated in the title. I am not sure why "venite prima possibile" is not correct.
Grazie.

Comment: Who says *venite prima possibile* is not correct? It sounds even better than the other version.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable. It means "Come as early as possible".

Comment: Which of the two phrases do you refer to by “it”? Plus, the question was «What is the function of *il*...»?

Comment: The one I.M. thinks to not be correct. It is perfectly acceptable. I agree with your comment.

Comment: They are both used and correct.

Comment: "Prima" means "before", not "soon", which is "presto" instead. So, "il prima possibile" should sound something like "the before possible", which obviously it's not correct, but maybe it helps to understand this way of saying. Even "il più presto possibile" is commonly used.

Comment: Interesting in this regard (in Italian): http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/presto-pi-presto-prima-possibile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Prima possibile" in "venite prima possibile" is an adverb, while "il prima possibile" in "venite il prima possibile" is something known as "avverbio sostantivato"; you can understand how the two expression are interpreted differently by comparing e.g. the English expression "come quickly" to "come the quickest you can";

When changing an adverb to an "avverbio sostantivato" it's mandatory to prepend, depending on the case, either "il" or "al" (much as in the English expression "come quickly" it's mandatory to prepend the "the" article: "come quickly" -> "come the quickest you can").

So they are both correct, but syntactically "prima possibile" is an adverb, while "il prima possibile" is an "avverbio sostantivato".